# Can someone please check my work on calculating the limit for this sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$a_n=(\frac{x^n}{2n+1})^\frac{1}{n}$$

This is my work so far:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x(\frac{1}{(2n+1)^{1/n}})$$

$$=x\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{1}{(2n+1)^{1/n}})$$

Then I take the natural log on both sides to get:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \ln(a_n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\ln(x)+\ln((\frac{1}{(2n+1)^{1/n}}))$$

$$=\ln(x)+\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\ln((\frac{1}{(2n+1)^{1/n}}))$$

$$=\ln(x)+\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \ln((2n+1)^{-1/n})$$

$$=\ln(x)+\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} -\frac{\ln(2n+1)}{n}$$

Applying L'Hopital:

$$=\ln(x)+\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{-2}{2n+1}=\ln(x)+0$$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{\ln(a_n)}=e^{\ln(x)+0}=e^{ln(x)}*e^0=x*e^0=x*1=x$$

I'm mostly concerned on if I applied the notation correctly with respect to the logarithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake in the first line after taking the natural logarithm, since $\ln(ab) \neq \ln(a)\ln(b)$ in general. There is a second mistake at the end, again since $e^{ab}\neq e^ae^b$ in general. The combination of these mistakes do cancel each other out to produce the correct answer through incorrect means.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was worried about. How can I fix the mistake?

Comment: Just use the correct log/exponent rules i.e. $\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)$ and $e^{ab}=({e^a})^b.$

Comment: Thanks, I just edited my answer. Would you mind checking and seeing if it's correct now?

Comment: It's correct. If you are happy with my answer, I suggest you mark it as correct so the question is closed.